Replaced key locks are not working after attempted car theft
1Five teenagers decided to "jump start" my old car for a tik tok challenge (trying to cut the ignition wires, like you see in the movies) and not only they destroyed the ignition but the locks as well (and failed.)
I have a 1996 Corolla. The collision shop claims they replaced both key locks but soon after I picked up the car, the passenger's side lock stopped working, and then the driver's side lock was not that great either. The locks are manual, and now the key gets stuck in the lock, and I have a hard time opening the doors.
The collision shop claims that they replaced the the passenger's side key lock, but that the reason it is not working is because I am not using it as much as the driver's side door lock. They assured me that if I used the key to open the passenger's door more often, it would work just fine.
I just picked up my car 2 weeks ago from their shop, so this seems kind of odd.
Then for the driver's side, they claim that the car is old anyway, and it is probably due to the entire lock panel inside the door not working properly, nothing to do with the key lock they said they replaced.
I had no prior issues with that lock.
I am trying to post a photo of the lock that was replaced but it doesn't look that new to me. Please help. Thanks!


If you are talking about auto locking the doors then The problem isn't necessary the lock itself but the mechanism that is required to get the door lock and unlocked. Some times they might have damage the inside mechanism in a way that it doesn't function the way that it supposedly should or the fuse or wires might be damaged from the inside. As long as you stick your keys in and be able to lock and unlock the vehicle then that means the lock is working fine.

The doors lock manually and the key now gets stuck in the lock. It's only been a couple of weeks since I picked up the car.

Since the key gets stuck inside the cylinder, it's likely just a low-quality part. I'd recommend buying compatible lock cylinders used (original) and re-keying, or getting them from Toyota.
